# how to get contents from a text file that is separated by multiple delimters in php

Tags: php

I have this text file which I would like to upload to my Database(oracle),
the file is like this:

```
D000000000000000xxxxxxxxxx**20180419**0000000000xxxxSome body's Name here                                         xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The areas marked 'x' are the values i would like to obtain. So far i've got:

```
$destination_file = "test.txt";
$file = file($destination_file, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
unset($file[0]);
$D='D000000000000000000';
$N='201804050000000000';
$A='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$parts=array();
foreach ($file as $files) {
    $parts = preg_replace('/('.$D.'|'.$N.')|[\s|'.$A.'|[()]/',',',$files);
    echo var_dump($parts);
{
```

which gives me this output:

> C:\wamp64\www\build\ui\test_textfile.php:37:string ',8325599,1426,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,000000078634,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,' (length=222)
>
> C:\wamp64\www\build\ui\test_textfile.php:37:string ',8421235,3900,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,000000085404,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,' (length=222)
>
> C:\wamp64\www\build\ui\test_textfile.php:37:string ',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,000000000000002,,,000000005326,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,' (length=257)

am I going in the right direction, if i want to store these values in an array? or is there any other efficient way?

Comment: What are the asterisks (**)? Delimiters?

Comment: D000000000000000xxxxxxxxxx and 0000000000xxxx always have the same lengths?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the input that gives that output with the code shown to get a clearer understanding of your requirements.  However, I think you probably should be using [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), using a pattern which captures what you want instead of trying to replace what you don't want.

Comment: hi, sorry the 'x' were supposed to represent any number, the asterisks(**) was me trying to put in bold the date '20180419'. Sometimes the number of the first line of numbers can vary in length from 7 numbers to 9, followed by the date, then 14 numbers, then alphabetic characters, followed by 12 numbers.

Comment: I'll need these numbers in order to insert them into my database..